# laravel: how to display the assets that are inside the Public folder

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.1, shared-hosting, laravel-storage

On the server (shared-hosting) all the assets that are inside the **public** folder are not displayed. i.e.

```
<img src="{{asset($painting->file)}}" >
```

output this

```
<img src="http://subdir.example.com/uploads/awJ4o8_miro1.jpg" >
```

it supposed to have a **public** folder

```
http://subdir.example.com/public/uploads/awJ4o8_miro1.jpg
```

On my Public_html folder I have this folder structure

```
PUBLIC_HTML
├───app
├───bootstrap
├───cgi-bin
├───config
├───database
├───public
│   ├───css
│   ├───img
│   ├───js
│   ├───uploads
│   └───videos
│   .htaccess(file)
│   .index.php(file)
├───resources
├───storage
└───tests
└   .htaccess(file)
```

both of the **.htaccess** file is like this file

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

permissions

[image]

So my questions is how can I set my configuration (.htaccess) so that I can display my assets on the shared-hosting site.

Comment: The generated url is correct, your `public` folder is your file root and should not be included in the url. Are you using `/public` to access your website?

Comment: hi @Jeredov . no I am not using `/publi/` to acess my webpage but if I change the **url** and add **public** into it everything works `http://miro.mongexweb.ca/public/uploads/NUsZlC__MG_5032.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert this rule just above last rule to redirect assets to `public/`:

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^uploads(/|$) /public%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301,NE]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can prefix the asset url with public as:

```
{{ asset('public/' . $painting->file) }}
```